# Lizmap error invalid cfg content

Tags: qgis, lizmap

Edit: my qgis desktiop is windows zanzibar 3.8.3; my lizmap web client is 3.3.0; my lizmap plugin version is 3.1.2.

I downloaded the example qgs content data here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/tree/master/exercise_data/world

and then I followed the guide here for using Lizmap plugin to generate Lizmap data: https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/lizmap_configuration.html

I opened the world.qgs file in my QGIS application and selected osm_mapnik layer and clicked "Apply" to generate a qgis.cfg file. Below is the content:

```
{
    "options": {
        "projection": {
            "proj4": "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs",
            "ref": "EPSG:4326"
        },
        "bbox": [
            4.847464273437447,
            7.93509594357638,
            35.058428482638845,
            25.562238756076383
        ],
        "mapScales": [
            10000,
            25000,
            50000,
            100000,
            250000,
            500000
        ],
        "minScale": 10000,
        "maxScale": 500000,
        "initialExtent": [
            4.847464273437447,
            7.93509594357638,
            35.058428482638845,
            25.562238756076383
        ],
        "googleStreets": "True",
        "osmMapnik": "True",
        "popupLocation": "dock",
        "pointTolerance": 25,
        "lineTolerance": 10,
        "polygonTolerance": 5,
        "tmTimeFrameSize": 10,
        "tmTimeFrameType": "seconds",
        "tmAnimationFrameLength": 1000,
        "emptyBaselayer": "True",
        "startupBaselayer": "osm-mapnik",
        "datavizLocation": "dock",
        "atlasLayer": "continents20120404114700542",
        "atlasDisplayLayerDescription": "True",
        "atlasHighlightGeometry": "True",
        "atlasZoom": "zoom",
        "atlasDisplayPopup": "True",
        "atlasMaxWidth": 25,
        "atlasDuration": 5
    },
    "layers": {
        "continents": {
            "id": "continents20120404114700542",
            "name": "continents",
            "type": "layer",
            "geometryType": "polygon",
            "extent": [
                -179.99999999990004,
                -55.91477792755927,
                180.00000000010004,
                83.63432689077342
            ],
            "crs": "EPSG:4326",
            "title": "continents",
            "abstract": "",
            "link": "",
            "minScale": 1,
            "maxScale": 1000000000000,
            "toggled": "False",
            "popup": "False",
            "popupSource": "auto",
            "popupTemplate": "",
            "popupMaxFeatures": 10,
            "popupDisplayChildren": "False",
            "noLegendImage": "False",
            "groupAsLayer": "False",
            "baseLayer": "False",
            "displayInLegend": "True",
            "singleTile": "True",
            "imageFormat": "image/png",
            "cached": "False",
            "clientCacheExpiration": 300
        }
    }
}
```

I then uploaded this entire folder to the lizmap/qgis server and then followed the guide here to setup a repository on lizmap server so I can view the map:
https://docs.lizmap.com/3.3/en/admin/lizmap-configuration.html#repositories

However, this didn't work and when I checked the log, I saw the following error:

```
2019-10-04 12:54:59 119.82.194.218  error   2019-10-04 12:54:59 119.82.194.218  [0] .qgs.cfg File of project world has invalid content  /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/classes/lizmapProject.class.php  271
    /index.php/view/
array (   'module' => 'view',   'action' => 'default:index', )

    0   lizmapProject->readProject()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/classes/lizmapProject.class.php : 189
    1   lizmapProject->__construct()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/classes/lizmap.class.php : 298
    2   lizmap::getProject()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/lizmap/classes/lizmapRepository.class.php : 150
    3   lizmapRepository->getProjects() /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/view/zones/main_view.zone.php : 47
    4   main_viewZone->_prepareTpl()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/utils/jZone.class.php : 239
    5   jZone->_createContent() /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/utils/jZone.class.php : 206
    6   jZone->getContent() /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/utils/jZone.class.php : 294
    7   jZone::_callZone()  /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/utils/jZone.class.php : 95
    8   jZone::get()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/tpl/jTpl.class.php : 125
    9   jTpl->assignZone()  /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/modules/view/controllers/default.classic.php : 101
    10  defaultCtrl->index()    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lib/jelix/core/jCoordinator.class.php : 225
    11  jCoordinator->process() /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.0/lizmap/www/index.php : 23
```

What am I missing here? What are the requirements to publishing a Lizmap map? I think the guide isn't sufficient enough.

Comment: Can you add your QGIS version, Lizmap QGIS plugin version and the Lizmap Web Client version?

Comment: hi @etrimaille, I have added the information to the post.

Comment: I would recommend downgrading the QGIS to the LTR version, because the lizmap development is still abit behind the current QGIS version. If that doesnt work you could try downgrading even more to the 2.X. I'm using the older version of QGIS (2.X) and things work smoothly. I mostly recommended other users that had similar problems to downgrade.